# Quando uma function terminar a outra termina também multiprocessing funções assíncronas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou usando a biblioteca `multiprocessing`, rodando duas `def` ao mesmo tempo, porém quero que ao terminar uma das duas `def` a outra que ainda está executando também termine no meio do processo.

Exemplo:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

def a():
    while True:
        print('a')
        break
        
def b():
    while True:
        print('b')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pA = Process(target=a)
    pB = Process(target=b)
```

Então... no código acima que jeito que faria para quando der o `break` na função `a`, consequentemente também terminasse a função `b` (que está se repetindo).

Agradeço Desde já

Comment: talvez usando a função [quit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used) no final das duas funções

Comment: Vou tentar armazenar os processos feitos em um list e passar esse list como parametro e então da terminate em cada um. Vou testar

Answer (score 1):

Neste seu caso eu usaria uma classe e consideraria uma variável interna da classe como parâmetro, faça o teste:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process


class Classe:
    processar = True

    def a(self):
        while True:
            print('a')
            break

        self.processar = False

    def b(self):
        while self.processar is True:
            print('b')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    classe = Classe()
    pA = Process(target=classe .a)
    pB = Process(target=classe .b)
```

Segue abaixo um modelo do que uso pessoalmente:

```py
import threading
import time


def run_thread(job_function):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_function)
    job_thread.start()


class Classe:
    processar = True

    def processar_a(self):
        for x in range(1, 100):
            print("processar_a: {}".format(str(x)))

        self.processar = False

    def processar_b(self):
        while self.processar is True:
            print("processar_b")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    classe = Classe()

    run_thread(job_function=classe.processar_a)
    run_thread(job_function=classe.processar_b)

    while classe.processar is True:
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Eu tinha resolvido com o Event() do multiprocessing, mas sua resposta foi a melhor solução que vi até agora, Obrigado.

Comment: Note que essa solução é para multi threading, não para multiprocessing. Em processos distintos, um worker não tem como "ver" o atributo da classe do outro worker - estão em processos separados - é necessário usar sim o Event, ou algum outro mecanismo de comunicação, como multiprocessing.Queue

Comment: a primeira listagem aqui não deve funcionar - como está, não faz nada mesmo, já que não é chamado o método ".start" de cada "Process"; eles são preparados, ficam prontos pra rodar e o programa se encerra. Se isso for arrumado, e o exemplo for alterado para algum que faça diferença o sinal (e não um único print em cada processo), não vai funcionar por que a classe está em processos diferentes - (e mesmo que estivesse no mesmo processo, não funcionaria por que são instancias separadas, cada uma veria seu `self.processar` distinto)

Comment: entendi seu ponto de vista, mas aqui nunca tive problemas das variáveis estarem em instâncias separadas pois foi declarado dentro de `classe = Classe()`. Mas pode ser que o último exemplo do Augusto Vasques seja a [melhor solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/504716/180585) do `multiprocessing`

Answer (score 1):

Se não há necessidade de termino imediato do processo `pB` é possível com o método [`terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) sinalizar de um processo a outro que seja finalizado passando sua referência por meio dos parâmetros `args` ou `kwargs` do constructor da classe [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process).

```
from multiprocessing import Process

#Parâmetro p é o processo que será finalizado ao termino dessa função.
def a(p):
    while True:
        print('a')            
        break
    p.terminate()             #Termina o processo p.
        
def b():
    while True:
        print('b')

#Troca a ordem de criação dos processos para que a referência pB fique disponível a pA no momento de sua criação.
pB = Process(target=b)                 
pA = Process(target=a,kwargs={"p":pB})
pB.start()                     #pB é inicializado primeiro pois do contrário pA pode terminar antes de pB começar.
pA.start()
pA.join()
pB.join()
```

Infelizmente inverter o raciocínio para testar dentro de `pB` se o processo `pA` inda está vivo com [`is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive) não funciona pois só o processo pai pode testar seus filhos:

```
#Esse código irá gerar erro...
from multiprocessing import Process

def a():
    while True:
        print('a')            
        break
      
def b(p):
    while p.is_alive():
        print('b')

          
pA = Process(target=a)
pB = Process(target=b, kwargs={"p": pA})       
pA.start()
pB.start()
pA.join()
pB.join()

Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 9, in b
    while p.is_alive():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 160, in is_alive
    assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only test a child process'
AssertionError: can only test a child process
```

Mas a verificação pode ser feita no processo principal onde tanto `pA` e `pB` são processos filhos:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def a():
    i = 0
    while i < 100:
        print('a')
        i+=1
        
def b():
    while True:
        print('b')

pA = Process(target=a)
pB = Process(target=b)
pB.start()
pA.start()
while pA.is_alive():
  pass
pB.terminate()
pA.join()
pB.join()
```